# Initialize Singleton variable in Startup and use it in wole app

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I want to store data in an object and I want to use this in the whole app. I created an Object and register as Singleton in *Program.cs*

Object:

```
 private Dictionary<string, string> _currentValues;

 public Dictionary<string, string> currentValues
 {
      get => _currentValues;
      set
      {
           _currentValues = value;
           StateHasChanged();
      }
}
```

Singleton Registration:

```
 services.AddSingleton<LocalizeData>();
```

In *program.cs* after registration I added initial data.

```
var _localizeData = host.Services.GetRequiredService<LocalizeData>();
_localizeData.currentValues = locaData;
```

Now I want to use these data in the whole app. I injected it main Page.

```
@LocalizeData localizeData
```

If I use now `localizeData.currentValues` the object is *null*.

What is missing. How can I initialize an object in `Starttup` and how can I use the data in whole app?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  :D

To use services in your component, you need to use the `inject` keyword:

```
@inject LocalizeData localizeData
```

Comment: I did that in the components as well. But unfortunately every time the Object will iniate with each injection new and the object is null. I thought If I register an singleton variable and init the object I can use this data in whole app. Isn't it?

What I need is an "globale" object which is initialize in startup. Is a Singleton not the right way?

Comment: Are you running WASM or Server?  If you're running WASM then the service is initialised every time you load the application, which may be what you're doing.  Also where do you get `LocaData`? You normally initialise data in a service in the initialisation method.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was I used

```
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

instead of

```
await host.RunAsync();
```

This was the reason why I created a second instance and I could not access my initialize data.

See documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly